# Spring Boot rest api unit tests - use of @Before

Tags: spring-boot, junit4

I have a setup for @Before that does
MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();

There is a data.sql for loading a few records into a H2 database. Is this loaded before each test? This is what I thought happened but now not sure.

I have one test that tests delete of record 2, one that tests update for record 2 and on the latter I get "record not found". If one is changed to record 1, then tests pass.

I could upgrade to junit 5 and use @order but at the moment I just want to know what should be happening.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[data.sql](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc) will only be initialised once

See the [@Sql](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-testing-annotation-sql) on how to configure integration tests.